# $C(n,p)$: even or odd?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, parity

Can we determine if a binomial coefficient $C(n,p)$ is even or odd, without calculating its value? 
($p\lt n$, $p$ and $n$ are positive integers)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem

Comment: Know someone say who is the author of the work contained in the file below?
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM4.pdf

Comment: @PauloArgolo Jonathan L. Gross

Answer (score 29):

There is a beautiful result of Kummer that says that if $q$ is a prime, then the largest power of $q$ that divides $\binom{m+n}{n}$, $m$ and $n$ nonnegative, is the number of carries when $m$ and $n$ are added in base $q$.

As a corollary, we get the Theorem of Lucas mentioned by Michael Lugo: we get a carry in the addition if and only if there is a $k$ such that the $k$th digit of $m+n$ in base $q$ is smaller than the $k$th digit in the base $q$ expansion of $n$, so $\binom{m+n}{n}$ is divisible by $q$ if and only if there is a $k$ such that the $k$th digit of the base $q$ expansion of $m+n$ is smaller than the $k$th digit of the base $q$ expansion of $n$.

Thus, to determine if $\binom{n}{p}$ is odd, you just need to know whether there is at least one carry when adding $p$ and $n-p$ in base $2$; you get a carry exactly when the $k$th binary digit of both $n-p$ and $p$ is $1$.

So just write $p$ and $n-p$ in binary, one digit at a time (from least significant to most significant digit), until you get that both are $1$; or write $p$ and $n$ one binary digit at a time, until you get a $1$ in $p$ and a $0$ in $n$. If this happens, $\binom{n}{p}$ is even; otherwise, it is odd.

Andrew Granville's paper [*Arithmetic properties of binomial coefficients*](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/Binomial/toppage.html) is chock full of interesting stuff about binomial coefficients and their divisibility. The proof of Kummer's Theorem can be found [there](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/paper/binomial/html/node3.html#SECTION00030000000000000000). There are also [other formats available](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/).

Comment: Nice! In C-style languages, then, it's just:  if (p & (n-p))

Comment: @TonyK: I don't think that's quite right; the bit-wise comparison would only give true if *all* bits are 1 in both, wouldn't it? You would need to do a disjunction of all the individual bit-comparisons. I recall you can easily extract the last bit, and shuffle to the right, so a simple loop-with-escape will do it.

Comment: in C-style languages, 'if (a & b)' evaluates to 'true' whenever a and b have at least one bit in common.

Comment: @TonyK Can't we just do `if(p & n)`? As $\binom{n}{p} = \binom{n}{n - p}$

Comment: @RezwanArefin That's wrong. Even if you use that formula (`C(n,p) = C(n,n-p)`) and replace `p` by `n-p`, then you will get `if((n-p)&(n-(n-p)))` that is just same as what TonyK told. In your suggestion you forgot to replace the first `p` in the expression.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.

We only need to know how many powers of two appear in the prime factorization of C(n,p). The number of powers of two that appear in the prime factorization of $n!$ is $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + \lfloor n/4 \rfloor + \lfloor n/8 \rfloor + \cdots$ -- count all the multiples of two, of four, of eight, and so on. This turns out to be $n$ minus the number of ones in the binary expansion of $n$.

It turns out that this reduces to the following: C(n,p) is odd if and only if every bit of the binary expansion of $p$ is less than or equal to the corresponding bit of the binary expansion of $n$. This is due to Lucas.

Answer (score 10):

I already commented with one Wikipedia link above, but I just want to add that if you run the Pascal's triangle recurrence $\bmod 2$ what you get is a sequence of approximations to the [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle).  So the result that comes out of Lucas' theorem is an explicit nonrecursive algorithm for plotting the Sierpinski triangle.

I also want to take this opportunity to mention a paper which discusses generalizations of this problem, and which is both quite entertaining to read and perhaps has one of the strangest titles of any math paper: Granville's [Zaphod Beeblebrox's Brain and the Fifth-Ninth Row of Pascal's Triangle](http://www.gianpierobiancoli.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/beeb.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Motivated by a duplicated question that has been asked today, I'd like to offer an alternative approach to the problem.

Let $C_n^r$ be the set of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that have cardinal $r$. Define the function $\sigma:C_n^r\to C_n^r$ given by
$$k\in\sigma(A)\Leftrightarrow n-k\in A$$
Let $S_n^r$ be the set of the fixed points of $\sigma$ and $T_n^r=C_n^r-S_n^r$. It is clear that $f\circ f=id$. Thus, $|T_n^r|$ is even and $|C_n^r|$ and $|S_n^r|$ have the same parity.

Let's study the parity of $|S_n^r|$. Represent each element of $A\in S_n^r$ with a binary word of length $n$ whose $k$th digit is $1$ if $k\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. So, the elements of $S_n^r$ are the symmetric words. For each of these symmetric words:

- **If $n$ is odd**, there is a central digit. If $r$ is odd it must be $1$, otherwise $0$. Any case, the word is determined by the $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ first digits and $\lfloor r/2\rfloor$ of these digits are $1$'s. Therefore,
  $$|S_n^r|=\binom{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}$$
- **If $n$ is even**, $r$ must be even and there must be $r/2$ of $1$'s each side. Then

$$|S_n^r|=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\binom{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}&\text{ if $r$ is even}\\
0&\text{ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.$$

Thus, we have a method that allows to obtain the parity of $\binom nr$ in at most $\log_2 r$ steps.

*Example*:
$$\binom{1000}{376}\equiv\binom{500}{188}\equiv\binom{250}{94}\equiv\binom{125}{47}\equiv\binom{62}{23}\equiv 0\pmod 2$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that noone mentioned this.

Here is a plot of the parity of ${n\choose p}$ for $n,p\le256$. Black is odd.

[image]

You get a pattern that is exactly the [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle). Analyzing this pattern leads naturally to a way to compute directly the parity of ${n\choose p}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even and $k$ is odd, then $\binom{n}{k}$ is always even, without any additional calculation or condition, see my proof at the and of [this](https://medium.com/@davidlaczkoo/simplified-notations-of-parity-and-their-application-to-results-of-operations-aa4bbac1c2bb?sk=8a613ea25487ac13eb610e8a4303376d) article.