# Binomial coefficient (mod m)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$n\ge k $
$ m>0$

How to find?
 $$\binom{n}{k}\mod m$$ without counting $n,k!$

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82336/11619) helps, when $p$ is a prime. A certain well known method then helps, if $m$ is square-free...

Comment: My friend published an [undergraduate paper](http://www.msri.org/~levy/files/Inv/2-4/involve-v2-n4-p04-p.pdf) that contains some results that might interest you. :)

Comment: This is too complicated for me. I thought that it will be easier. I needed it to use in program written in C.

Comment: If it's a programming question, you should post it to the programming website, not here.

Comment: See this related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/cn-p-even-or-odd