# Maximal $k$ such that ${{n+k+1}\choose{n+1}}$ is odd

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, parity

How to compute the maximal $k$ such that
$
1\leq k\leq n
$ 
and

$$ {{n+k+1}\choose{n+1}}  
$$

is odd?

Given $n$, suppose this maximal number is $f(n)$. I want to obtain the explicit expression of the function $f$.

Comment: Related: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I allow $0\le k\le n$ to avoid an annoying technicality (that technicality being that disallowing $k=0$ leads to no solutions in some cases).

By [Lucas's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) a binomial coefficient $\binom{s}{t}$ is odd if and only each of the binary digits of $s$ is greater than or equal to the corresponding binary digit of $t$.

Letting $n+1=t$, we are looking for the largest $s$ which fits the above criteria such that $t\le s\le 2t-1$.

Now let's take the binary representation of $t=\left(b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_0\right)_2$ where $b_m=1$ and $b_i\in\{0,1\}$. Multiplying by $2$ gives $2t=\left(b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_00\right)_2=2^{m+1}+\left(b_{m-1}\dots b_10\right)_2$. Note now that 
$$\left(b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_0\right)_2>\left(b_{m-1}\dots b_00\right)_2$$
because the first $0$ in the right-hand expression appears before the first $0$ in the left-hand expression.

Hence if each digit of $s$ is bigger than or equal to the corresponding digit of $t$ and $s<2t$, we in fact need $s<2^{m+1}$. Now we notice that $2^{m+1}-1$ is the maximal such number and has all $1$s in its binary expansion (so each digit is bigger than or equal to the corresponding digit in $t$).

We conclude 
$$\binom{s}{t}=\binom{2^{m+1}-1}{t}$$
is the last odd binomial coefficient where $t\le s\le 2t-1$ and $2^m$ is the largest power of $2$ less than $t$ (notice that we can represent this as $m=\left\lfloor\log_2t\right\rfloor$).

Converting back to the original formulation, we get 
$$f(n)=2^{\left\lfloor\log_2(n+1)\right\rfloor+1}-n-2$$

Comment: (I only noticed the explicit definition of $m$ after looking at user153012's answer)

Comment: The *bigger* and *greater than* need an *or equal*.

Comment: @ccorn right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The explicit expression what I've found:
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}  -\infty, & \mbox{if $n$ has the form $2^{j-2}-2$} \\  2^{1+\left\lfloor\log_2{\left(n+1\right)}\right\rfloor}-n-2,  & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I've conjectured this function by calculating a few terms of the sequence $f$.

Comment: Do you happen to have a proof of that, or is it just a conjecture? It's not clear.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It is a conjecture.

Comment: So this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's actually true, by [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_theorem), though I'd replace $-\infty$ with $0$.

Comment: @ccom $k \geq 1$.