# Faster way to calculate the amount of odd coefficients of $(x+1)^{1000}$

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a faster way to calculate the amount of odd coefficients of $(x+1)^{1000}$ besides going over all the options with the combinations formula?

I also tried to look at the amount of odd coefficients by going over the first $10$ series of Pascal's triangle to get a sequence. I didn't find it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/cn-p-even-or-odd

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001316

Answer (score 0):

Use recurrence relations for *n!/(n-r)!*

There are quite a few, work from smaller n to larger n.